# How To Use drop_event on Filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I have some logs that collect from autodiscover using kubernetes. I want to drop the logs if the logs contains some word. I want to drop this kind of log:

> 130.211.2.205 - - [26/Oct/2021:17:10:50 +0000] "GET /stickearn-auth/check HTTP/1.1" 302 5722 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.0 Safari/605.1.15"

This is my filebeat.yml:

```
    filebeat.autodiscover:
      providers:
       - type: kubernetes
         node: ${NODE_NAME}
         hints.enabled: true
         templates:
            - condition:
                equals:
                  kubernetes.namespace: default
              config:
                - type: container
                  paths:
                    - /var/log/containers/*${data.kubernetes.container.id}.log

    processors:
      - drop_event:
          when.regexp:
            message: 'GET'

    output.logstash:
      hosts: ['logstash:5044']
```

I tried to using regexp, not.contains and also exclude_lines with value 'GET' (on processors), but still not work and still delivered to logstash. How to drop this kind of logs with processors on filebeat? many thanks

Comment: Did/does separating the `when:` and the `- regexp:` to individual lines work?

Comment: Can you try with `when.contains` instead of regexp?